# How to use fitdist correctly?

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

I want to fitting about Generalized normal distribution. However, the R code for performing this was input, and the following error occurred. I really need your help to solve this. Help me.

```
library(fitdistrplus)
data(mtcars)
head(mtcars)
fit <- fitdist(mtcars$mpg, "gnorm", start=list(mean=mean(mtcars$mpg), 
                                               sd=sd(mtcars$mpg), 
                                               shape=0))
```

The following are the results of the implementation.

```
> fit <- fitdist(mtcars$mpg, "gnorm", 
+                start=list(mean=mean(mtcars$mpg), 
+                           sd=sd(mtcars$mpg), 
+                           shape=0))
Error in checkparamlist(arg_startfix$start.arg, arg_startfix$fix.arg,  : 
'start' must specify names which are arguments to 'distr'.
```

I want an R code that can solve these problems, and I want a brief description of it.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check `help("dgnorm")` for the parameters you need to specify. `library(gnorm); fit <- fitdist(mtcars$mpg, "gnorm", start=list(mu=mean(mtcars$mpg),                                                alpha=1, beta=1))`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried as you told, but I still have a problem. The results are as follows. > fit <- fitdist(mtcars$mpg, "gnorm", start=list(mu=mean(mtcars$mpg), alpha=1, beta=1))
Not defined for negative values of alpha and/or beta.

Comment: I got the same messages but the algorithm converged successfully to parameter estimates that were all positive.

Comment: May I know the example data that you have successfully performed? Something simple is fine.

Comment: Yes, you may. I used `mtcars$mpg` as per your example.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally, I solved the problem. Parameters were successfully estimated. :)